# Make Service for get Call Logs

Tags: android

I make a program that after booting it will get a call logs into a String, the function to get the call logs is running on Service class, but when i write the code to get the call logs i got an error

Here my code

```
public void callLogs(){
        Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int date = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int type = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

        mCursor.moveToLast();
        int counter = 0;
        do{
            String phnNumber = mCursor.getString(number);
            String callDuration = mCursor.getString(duration);
            String callType = mCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = mCursor.getString(date);
            Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callTypeStr = "";
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode){

            case  CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                callTypeStr = "Outgoing";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                callTypeStr = "Incoming";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                callTypeStr = "Missed";
                break;
                }

        sb.append("\nPhone number :" + phnNumber);
        sb.append("\nCall Duration :" + callDuration + "sec");
        sb.append("\nCall type :" + callTypeStr);
        sb.append("\nCall date :" + d);
        sb.append("\n-------------------");
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        counter++;

        }
        while(mCursor.moveToPrevious() && counter<=15);{
        }


        String finalSb = new String(sb);
}
```

and i got error 
"The method managedQuery(Uri, null, null, null, null) is undefined for the type TestService"

Answer (score 0):

As far as im aware you need to specify 'Activity' on managedQuery.

```
e.g. getActivity().managedQuery...
```

However, i would recommend you not use it. Give it was deprecated in API 11, in favour of CursorLoader

[API Doc for ManagedQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String))

Create a variable at the top of the page like:

```
Activity myAcc;
```

Say your class name is 'myClass', make a function like:

```
public myClass(Activity acc)
{
    this.myAcc = acc;
}
```

Then change your function to

```
public void callLogs(Activity acc){
    Cursor mCursor = acc.managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    ...
}
```

And when you call the function:

```
callLogs(myAcc);
```

Comment: but i make the code in a class, not activity, how to solve it? im new for android. Please help me

Comment: Pass a reference to your activity/context in the constructor of the class if you wish

Comment: can you give me the simple example?